# Bitmap maximum size before outofmemoryexception

Tags: c#, image

My website integrates a plugin that allows the user to upload pictures to it.

It works fine with most pictures but will raise an OutOfMemoryException on any pictures that it feels are too large.

Here is the code that crashes :

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
Image test = (Image)(new Bitmap(img, new Size(img.Width, img.Height))); //OutOfMemoryException
```

It really is all about resolution as :

Image 1 => 3.79Mb, 4200x2850 ***does not crash***

Image 2 => 1.82Mb, 7360x4912 ***causes a crash***

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Sadly, `OutOfMemoryException` doesn't always mean you run out of memory - it's a generic GDI+ error. What happens if you resize the first image to 7360x4912, does it still cause the crash? It's quite possible that the second image is corrupted in some way, for example. Well, and of course, the size before converting to `Bitmap` is meaningless - if it's a 32-bit image, it will take ~140 MiB of memory, regardless of the input file size.

Comment: For a start, your calculations on memory used by images is optimistic at best, as you're comparing compressed sizes with memory. Consider a pixel taking 4bytes per pixel, gives closer to 138Mb for the second image (which you'd already allocated memory for once), and assuming a 32bit application, you've a total of 2Gb of address space for all your objects - have you checked actual memory usage when it crashes? Does it crash if you only copy that image?

Comment: Luaan, I just tried resizing an image to 7360x4912 and it works perfectly fine. No clue why it gets angry about the other one. Rowland Shaw, the memory usage doesn't go up in any kind of way before the crash it all happens really fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error was occurring on an MVC web application. It was caused by running a 32-bit IISEXPRESS server which forced the memory allocation of the bitmap to be contiguous instead of using any available chunks.

The solution was to force IISEXPRESS to run in 64-bit by going into the following Visual Studio settings :

TOOLS>OPTIONS>Projects and Solutions>WEB PROJECT and check the 64-bit IISEXPRESS box